# Ver todos os valores de um array

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como poderei ver todos os valores de um array quando faço o print dá-me isto:

```
ber_MFSK        = M/2*qfunc(np.sqrt(k*ebno_theory))
print(ber_MFSK)
```

e dá-me isto:

```
[  1.58655254e-01   1.30927297e-01   1.04028637e-01 ...,   7.82701129e-04
   1.93985472e-04   3.43026239e-05]
```

como poderei ver os outros valores

Comment: O problema é em relação ao `...`? Por que você não faz um `for item in ber_MFSK` e da um `print(item)`?

Comment: sim é esse o problema , a sugestão resolveu o problema, obrigado

Answer (score 4):

As NumPy Arrays costumam "resumir" a exibição de grandes conteúdos e controlam isso por meio da configuração de um `threshold` (limite) que pode ser configurado por meio do método `set_printoptions()`.

Para que a exibição de uma NumPy Array **nunca** seja exibido resumidamente você pode fazer algo como:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions( threshold=np.nan )
```

Exibe arrays de até 10 elementos sem resumir o conteúdo:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions( threshold=10 )
print(np.arange(10))
```

Saída:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Exibe arrays de até 9 elementos sem resumir o conteúdo:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions( threshold=9 )
print(np.arange(10))
```

Saída:

```
[0 1 2 ..., 7 8 9]
```

Referência:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html